# PHP: A better way than these nested loops?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested-loops

i want to access the data inside this array to do a comparison on it

```
$roomSensors =

Array
(
    [maple] => Array
        (
            [room1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [room2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                )

        )
)
```

i want to compare an array of numbers like this:

```
$sensorsInHit =

Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

to the the 'room' arrays in the first array

heres the loop that i used to do this, it works but i think its kind of ugly and long winded.

```
// each 'ward' has an array of 'rooms'

foreach ($roomSensors as $ward => $rooms) {

                // looping through each room in the rooms array
                // the values are arrays of bluetooth sensor ids

                foreach ($rooms as $room => $sensors){

                    // at this point i would like to just compare
                    // the sensorsInHit array to the $sensors array
                    // but i couldnt find a function that allows
                    // to see if one of the values in one array
                    // is equal to one of the values in another array
                    // so i just loop through the array and compare
                    // and compare single values to the array

                    foreach ($sensorsInHit as $sensor){                      

                        if (in_array($sensor, $sensors)){

                            // do loads of stuff

                            break;
                        }                        
                    }
                    break;
                }
}
```

uncommented

```
foreach ($roomSensors as $ward => $rooms) {

                foreach ($rooms as $room => $sensors){

                    foreach ($sensorsInHit as $sensor){                      

                        if (in_array($sensor, $sensors)){

                            // do loads of stuff                             

                            break;
                        }                        
                    }
                    break;
                }
}
```

i know they are not massive arrays of values and dont take long to loop through but i would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this?

thanks for any help!

Comment: recursion is the answer

Comment: This might be a better question to ask on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: maybe array_diff helps...have you looked?

Comment: after looking into using recursive functions for going through arrays, it looks like this is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP array_intersect function:

```
foreach ($roomSensors as $ward => $rooms) {
    foreach ($rooms as $room => $sensors){
        $matches = array_intersect($sensors, $sensorsInHit);
        if (count($matches) > 0){
            // do loads of stuff  
            break;
        }                           
    }
}
```

Matches will contain all of the values in $sensors that are also in $sensorsInHit.